# assign value to select box ( form validation )

Tags: javascript, validation

I am creating some form validation, and I have fields working great.
The trickyness seems to arise from parsing value from select box

I know how to assign the value within form element, we have:

```
<select id="sms" name="sms" class="medium">

                                <optgroup label="SMS Alerts">
                                  <option value="">Please choose</option>
                                  <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                  <option value="0">No</option>
                                </optgroup>
                            </select>
```

But I am not sure what to do within the js for select box.

Currently for a field I have:

```
$("#mobile").blur(function() { 
        if(validate_form_field($(this), $(this).val().length>9)) {
            mobile_passed = true;
        } else {
            mobile_passed = false;
        }
    });
```

Essentially, I want to validate that value =1 from select box. Do I do something like ?

```
$("#sms").blur(function() { 
        if(validate_form_field($(this), $(this).val().length=1)) {
            sms_passed = true;
        } else {
            sms_passed = false;
        }
    });
```

Cheers Ste

ADDED Info:

The form is to propagate a progress bar.

So here is a portion of the script, split into 3 main parts within js. I have included field and the select box, to see where I am goin wrong.

```
var mobile_passed = false;
var sms_passed = false;

$("#mobile").blur(function() { 
        if(validate_form_field($(this), $(this).val().length>9)) {
            mobile_passed = true;
        } else {
            mobile_passed = false;
        }
    });

    $("#sms").blur(function() { 
        if(validate_form_field($(this), $(this).val().length=1)) {
            sms_passed = true;
        } else {
            sms_passed = false;
        }
    });

var $object_mobile = $("#mobile");
    no_errors = validate_form_field($object_mobile, $object_mobile.val().length>9);

    var $object_sms = $("#sms");
    no_errors = validate_form_field($object_sms, $object_sms.val().length=1);
```

**Plan B**

What if I ditch the select box idea, and add an input field as I know these work.
But validate if user types YES

How would I achieve that ??

Comment: You should be able to just take the .length off and just use $(this).val() = 1. What does the validate_form_field function do?

Comment: could it be because I am parsing validate_form_field
When in fact in the html, the id is <select id="sms" name="sms" class="medium"> instead of <field id="sms" name="sms" class="medium">

I ahve tried your sugestion Aaron, but think it could be more an issue with the html

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sms").blur(function() { 
    if(validate_form_field($('#sms option:selected').val()), $('#sms option:selected').val().length=1)) {
        sms_passed = true;
    } else {
        sms_passed = false;
    }
});
```